# Wordpress . How to display the views a post has?

Tags: php, wordpress, function

The code is not mine, I found it in a Youtube tutorial.
What I want is to display the number of views a post has, but just by clicking and entering into the post.
The function that I have adds a view every time I refresh the page, so why would it add a view if I yet have not clicked on the post?
Can anyone help me to solve this?

This is what I have in my functions file

```
    // Views per post/page
//// Add counts views per post by refreshing(F5) the current post
//Set the Post Custom Field in the WP dashboard as Name/Value pair 
function addview($post_ID) {

    //Set the name of the Posts Custom Field.
    $count_key = 'post_views_count'; 

    //Returns values of the custom field with the specified key from the specified post.
    $count = get_post_meta($post_ID, $count_key, true);

    //If the the Post Custom Field value is empty. 
    if($count == ''){
        // $count = 0; // set the counter to zero.

        //Delete all custom fields with the specified key from the specified post. 
        delete_post_meta($post_ID, $count_key);

        //Add a custom (meta) field (Name/value)to the specified post.
        add_post_meta($post_ID, $count_key, '0');
        return $count . ' View';

    //If the the Post Custom Field value is NOT empty.
    }else{
        $count++; //increment the counter by 1.
        //Update the value of an existing meta key (custom field) for the specified post.
        update_post_meta($post_ID, $count_key, $count);

        //If statement, is just to have the singular form 'View' for the value '1'
        if($count == '1'){
        return $count . ' View';
        }
        //In all other cases return (count) Views
        else {
        return $count . ' Views';
        }
    }
}
```

and this what I have in my index and single files:

```
<?php if(function_exists('addview')) { echo addview(get_the_ID()); }?>
```

Comment: Use a plugin like Post Views Counter which already has all this functionality to do it for you.  Usually you would set a cookie or transient to log when a user has visited the page so no further page refreshes would increment the counter.  https://en-au.wordpress.org/plugins/post-views-counter/

Comment: sorrry for the late answer, but I already fixed it without having to use a plugin :) [http://wp-snippets.com/post-views-without-plugin/

Comment: There's nothing in that code that is tracking what user is visiting the page so if the same user comes back multiple times the count will increment.

Answer (score 0):

Add this code to your functions.php

```
function totalView($id){
    $count = 1;
    $check = get_post_meta($id, 'count',true);
    if(!$check){
        add_post_meta($id,'count',$count,true);
    }else{
        $inc = $check+1;
        $a = update_post_meta($id,'count',$inc);
    }
    return 'Total views:&nbsp;<b>'.get_post_meta($id, 'count',true).'</b> &nbsp; times';
}
```

Then call this functions from your index, single or anyother file.